# Transpose and expand data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id     begcost     endcost
100    1           3
200    10          12
```

I want:

```
id      newcost
100     1 
100     2
100     3
200     10
200     11
200     12
```

Basically I need to create a new row for each value contained within the range in the begcost and endcost columns. Have tried multiple transpose options but cannot seem to hit on what I need TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(i, j) for i, b, e in df.itertuples(index=False) for j in range(b, e + 1)],
    columns=['id', 'newcost']
)

    id  newcost
0  100        1
1  100        2
2  100        3
3  200       10
4  200       11
5  200       12
```

---

**Timing**

```
%%timeit
(df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(x.iloc[0],x.iloc[1]+1)), axis=1)
            .reset_index()
            .melt(id_vars='id')
            .drop('variable', axis=1)
            .rename(columns={'value':'newcost'}))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.03 ms per loop

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(
    [(i, j) for i, b, e in df.itertuples(index=False) for j in range(b, e + 1)],
    columns=['id', 'newcost']
)
​
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: Now, that is some performance improvement! Out of votes for today, you get my upvote tomorrow.

Comment: @ScottBoston as long as I have your respect... that's all I need :-)... but I'll take the vote, of course!

Answer (score 4):

```
df_out = (df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(x.iloc[0],x.iloc[1]+1)), axis=1)
            .reset_index()
            .melt(id_vars='id')
            .drop('variable', axis=1)
            .rename(columns={'value':'newcost'}))
```

Output:

```
    id  newcost
0  100        1
1  200       10
2  100        2
3  200       11
4  100        3
5  200       12
```

Comment: You guys are awesome!

Comment: @A-Za-z... piRSquared is the man, I am simply learning from him.

Comment: I like both solutions :)

Comment: He is the god in fact, doesn't make your solution any less :) Anyway, its +1 for both of you